# Multitask learning in Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have two different datasets and I would like to try multi-task learning. My problem is that all the examples I could find have two different training inputs, but the labels are the same. My question is: can I have different labels? This is my code right now:

```
input1 = Sequential()
input1.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_size, 
input_length=longest_sen_input1))
input1.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=embedding_size)))
input1.add(Dense(len(document), activation='softmax'))

input2 = Sequential()
input2.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_size, 
input_length=longest_sen_input2))
input2.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=embedding_size)))
input2.add(Dense(len(document), activation='softmax'))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([input1, input2], mode='sum'))
model.add(Dense(len(document), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam')

model.fit([X_train_input1, X_train_input2], [Y_train_input1, Y_train_input2], epochs=100)
```

I try to insert [Y_train_input1, Y_train_input2], but I have this error:

```
Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   ...,
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0....
```

Does anybody know how to perform multitask learning with two inputs (X_train_input1/Y_train_input1 and X_train_input2/Y_train_input2) returning a common prediction?

*EDIT*
My model seems to work now, I simply changed

```
model.fit([X_train_input1, X_train_input2], [Y_train_input1, Y_train_input2], epochs=100)
```

in

```
model.fit([X_train_input1, X_train_input2], Y_train, epochs=100)
```

but then I try to test the model like this

```
multitask_model.predict_classes(X_test)
```

and I have this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model : the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,  13,   8, 134],
   [  0,   0,   0, ...,  33,  87,  19],
   [  0,   0,   0, ...,  27,   1,   4],
   ...,
   [  0,   0,   0, ...,   1,  10,   8],
   [  0...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can use keras functional API (https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Comment: Hello @Maria, since you created a model that takes two inputs, it will always take two inputs (X1 and X2). I'm not sure about your intention, if you really wanted two different parallel models to predict one result, or maybe you were trying to simply accelerate one model by using it twice. Any way, your training and predicting should follow the same number of inputs and outputs. (Unless you build more models taking parts of these ones)

Comment: I think maybe you should create a detailed question stating exactly what you expect from each model, if they're the same or different, why you're trying to predict differently from training, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model has only one output, and you're passing two: `Y_train_input1`,  `Y_train_input2`.

If your goal is not to merge both models then you should keep them separate. When you merge/sum the outputs, you end up with only one output.

Is your intention to really have two different separate models without any interaction between them?

- Either you have a common output and a common `Y_train`, or
- You have two separate outputs and two different targets.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand your point! What I want is to merge the layers in order to have one single output, but my current problem is that I have different labels for the two input data. So, if I only want one output, I guess I have to modify my labels in order for Y_train_input1 and Y_train_input2 to be the same, correct?

Comment: I just had another problem, I edited it in the question. Do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: if we have a common output and a common Y_train then we will face another problem which is the different sample of training data which means the length of the two datasets are different even though they have similar classes but still the length of the classes also different now this is my problem:        All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(24424, 15, 12), (16325, 15, 12)]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem using this `y_pred = model.predict([X_test,X_test]).argmax(axis=1)`
 you have to pass two arrays instead of one